# Newsfeed from LayoutInflater doesn't work

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, layout-inflater

I want to create newsfeed inside my app which takes a data from MySQL. For this purpose, I use `LayoutInflate` and FOR loop.

If I write lines (specified below **bold**) inside `onCreateView` the app does correctly but a screen display only one last news (cotitle, time and section). In case if inside FOR loop in method `newsFeedDisplay()` app doesn't and indicates error NPE.

```
LayoutInflater infl_news = getLayoutInflater();

final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.linear_newsfeed);

final View view1 = infl_news.inflate(R.layout.newsfront, linearLayout, false);
```

I checked via Log and saw that a data entering from DB is correctly (DB has four news).

What must I do that the screen displays a right number of news? How correctly to make that to display multiple `LayoutInflater` in sequence (one under another)?

Below code which bold lines writing inside FOR loop.

***NewsFeed.java***

```
public class NewsFeed extends Fragment {

public NewsFeed() {
}

TextView newsTime;
TextView newsTitle;
TextView newsSection;

String id_news;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsfeed, container, false);

    newsTime = (TextView)rv.findViewById(R.id.newsTime);
    newsTitle = (TextView)rv.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
    newsSection = (TextView)rv.findViewById(R.id.newsSection);
/*        Typeface GothamProFont = 
Typeface.createFromAsset(getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/GothamPro.ttf");
        newsTime.setTypeface(GothamProFont);
        newsTitle.setTypeface(GothamProFont);
        newsSection.setTypeface(GothamProFont);*/

    newsFeedDisplay();

/*        view1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), NewsBody.class);
            intent.putExtra("id_news", id_news);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });*/
    return rv;
}

void newsFeedDisplay () {

    LayoutInflater infl_news = getLayoutInflater();
    final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.linear_newsfeed);
    final View view1 = infl_news.inflate(R.layout.newsfront, linearLayout, false);

    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("news");
                    Log.i(C.T, String.valueOf(jsonMainNode.length()));

                HashMap<String,String> map;

                for(int i=0; i<jsonMainNode.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);

                    id_news = c.getString("news_id");
                    String time = c.getString("time");
                    String title = c.getString("title");
                    String section = c.getString("section");
                    Log.i (C.T, id_news);

                    String time1 = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm").format(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(time));

                    newsTime.setText(time1);
                    newsTitle.setText(title);
                    newsSection.setText(section);

                    linearLayout.addView(view1);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    NewsFeedRequest3 newsFeedRequest3 = new NewsFeedRequest3(responseListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    queue.add(newsFeedRequest3);
}
}
```

***newsfeed.xml***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linear_newsfeed"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="blazhko.sportarena.main_screen.NewsFeed">

</LinearLayout>
```

***NewsFeedRequest3.java***

```
public class NewsFeedRequest3 extends StringRequest{

private static final String REGISTER_REQUEST_URL = "https://blazhko.000webhostapp.com/test.php";
private Map<String, String> params;

public NewsFeedRequest3(Response.Listener<String> listener){
    super(Method.POST, REGISTER_REQUEST_URL, listener, null);
      params = new HashMap<>();
      //params.put("section", section);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams() {
    return params;
}
}
```

***newsfront.xml*** (I draw face of a news for newsfeed here)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/exmpTime"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="3dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/newsTime"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextTitle"
        android:lineSpacingMultiplier="1.3"
        android:text="@string/exmpTitle"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newsSection"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/newsTime"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="17dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="@string/exmpSection"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWarning"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/linebelownews"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/newsTitle"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="13dp"
        android:background="@color/colorAccent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

***Error***

```
*FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: blazhko.yevgen, PID: 18136
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
at blazhko.sportarena.main_screen.NewsFeed$1.onResponse(NewsFeed.java:99)
at blazhko.sportarena.main_screen.NewsFeed$1.onResponse(NewsFeed.java:78)*
```

Please help me.

Comment: Use a RecyclerView and don't directly create views after network call because the fragment could be dead (see rotation etc)

Comment: You did not findViewById for your child elements (newsTime, newsTitle,..) in the loop

Comment: @nhoxbypass why? I did it in onCreateView. Is it incorrect?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce RecyclerView will displays elements by round with repeat. It does not suit way for newsfeed. There have other ways?